# Are variadic mixin templates possible in D?

Tags: templates, d, mixins, variadic-templates

Suppose I need to do something similar to this:

```
mixin(some_template!("x", "foo"));

mixin(some_template!("x", "bar"));

mixin(some_template!("x", "baz"));

mixin(some_template!("y", "foo"));

mixin(some_template!("y", "bar"));

mixin(some_template!("z", "baz"));
```

Is it somehow possible to create `another_template` which is a variadic version of `some_template`, where you can give anywhere from 2 to however-many arguments? What I mean is that I would like to be able to say:

```
mixin(another_template!("x", "foo", "bar", "baz"));

mixin(another_template!("y", "foo", "bar"));

mixin(another_template!("z", "baz"));
```

and have it expand to equivalent code to what the first example would expand to.

Comment: Just a technicality note on the terms: those aren't mixin templates, those are just template functions returning strings being passed to a mixin statement. Mixin templates are a different beast used to add declarations instead of returning code as a string.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `mixin some_template!("x", "foo");`?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe has it right - they basically return strings to mixin statements. The idea is to eliminate boilerplate, but I'm not precisely sure how to call this... pattern? Idiom? Some other thing? Essentially, what I want is to make the templates that return those strings which get passed to ``mixin`` to be variadic.

Comment: Now you tell me... :/

Comment: @CyberShadow: Sorry - as my volume (and occasional obviousness) of D questions on here shows, I'm not the most proficient D programmer. I'll upvote your answer anyway.

Comment: I think both techniques are valuable to know anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using the regular variadic template syntax (`Something...` collects the rest of the template arguments given and they can be of mixed types. see: http://dlang.org/template#TemplateTupleParameter):

```
string some_template(strings...)() {
        string a;
        foreach(f; strings)
                a ~= f;
        return a;
}

void main() {
        mixin(some_template!("int ", "giggle", ";"));
}
```

You can restrict the type with a constraint like this:

```
// this condition will only compile if it is passed a string
import std.typetuple;
enum check_if_string(string s) = true;

// then we check that they all compile with the check_if_string check
string some_template(strings...)() if(allSatisfy!(check_if_string, strings)) {
        string a;
        foreach(f; strings)
                a ~= f;
        return a;
}
```

The error message will be ugly though, and non-strings won't compile even without this check so it isn't really important. But you can also use the if check in there for like `if(strings.length >= 2)` as well.

This is called a template constraint: http://dlang.org/template#Constraint

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes you really meant [template mixins](http://dlang.org/template-mixin.html), and not templated functions.

Yes, you can declare variadic template parameters, e.g.:

```
mixin template another_template(string A, Bs...)
```

Then, you can use `static if` and recursive instantiation to process the whole list.

Full example:

```
mixin template some_template(string A, string B)
{
    pragma(msg, "some_template: " ~ A ~ ", " ~ B);
}

mixin template another_template(string A, Bs...)
{
    mixin some_template!(A, Bs[0]);
    static if (Bs.length > 1)
        mixin another_template!(A, Bs[1..$]);
}

mixin another_template!("x", "foo", "bar", "baz");

mixin another_template!("y", "foo", "bar");

mixin another_template!("z", "baz");
```